# Matching a Digital Image's Color to a Scan

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, color-match

I am attempting to clean up some very high resolution scans of pictures, however, while the scans do not have terrible colors, they are off from the originals. I have very low resolution digital copies of the images with accurate colors.

I am trying to match the colors of the low resolution original to that of the high resolution scan, but I'm wondering if there's a better process than simply eyeballing it with levels, curves, and hue/saturation adjustments.

I have attempted the Match Color tool with limited success. Any tips or suggestions?

Comment: I don't know where it is in PS, but the technique is called [Histogram matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_matching).

Answer (score 2):

One Answer is called color-management.
You could profile your scanner with an X-Rite Colorchecker card and an X-Rite software or something like Argyll-CMS

Answer (score 0):

Open the scanned images in Photoshop

Take a Curve Adjustment layer.

In the curve dialog box, Click on the black point tool, and click on the image where you think it could be pure black.

Similarly in the Curve dialog, take the white point tool and click on the possible white part of the image.

Adjust the transparency of the Curve Adjustment layer to fade the adjustment.